# How to insert an image into sqlite database?

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have tried the following code :

1.Code to convert bitmap to byte array :

```
private byte[] bitmaptoByteArray( Bitmap bmp)
      {
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
          byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
          return byteArray;
      }
```

2.Code which to insert the values into DB

```
  public void insertIntoImageTable( int companyid , String productname , String productdesc , byte[] bmp )
      {
          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(dataBaseHelper.COMPANY_ID, companyid);           
            values.put(dataBaseHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, productname);
            values.put(dataBaseHelper.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, productdesc);
            values.put(dataBaseHelper.PRODUCT_IMAGE, bmp);
            try
            {
                db.insert(dataBaseHelper.IMAGE_DATA, null, values);
            }
            catch( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
```

I get nullpointer exception.

Call from the function to put data into DB :

```
   insertIntoImageTable( 7 , productname[0] , productdesc[0] , barry);
```

All the three bits of code are in the same class file.

Edit: The stack trace is as below.

```
03-24 16:04:26.245: WARN/System.err(13255): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 16:04:26.265: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.sqlQueries.insertIntoImageTable(sqlQueries.java:101)
03-24 16:04:26.275: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.sqlQueries.upLoadtoDatabase(sqlQueries.java:118)
03-24 16:04:26.305: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.ImageAdapter.<init>(ImageAdapter.java:58)
03-24 16:04:26.315: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.imageGridView.onCreate(imageGridView.java:42)
03-24 16:04:26.335: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-24 16:04:26.335: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-24 16:04:26.355: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-24 16:04:26.385: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-24 16:04:26.385: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-24 16:04:26.415: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 16:04:26.415: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-24 16:04:26.435: WARN/System.err(13255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-24 16:04:26.445: WARN/System.err(13255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 16:04:26.455: WARN/System.err(13255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-24 16:04:26.475: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-24 16:04:26.475: WARN/System.err(13255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-24 16:04:26.505: WARN/System.err(13255):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show the exception please. And do it every time you have one.

Comment: Seems you have db variable null.

Comment: it is a null pointer exception

Comment: this one , db.insert(dataBaseHelper.IMAGE_DATA, null, values);

Comment: Base64 encode your image and store it as text. It makes it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your database is null or `productname[0],`productdesc[0]`or`barry` is null.

In general when saving large files on Android, you should save the file to disk (maybe the SD card if it's available) and then store the file URI in the database. The SQLite database on Android is not really designed for storing large content - you'll getter performance storing large files directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you instantiated your dataBaseHelper and checked the database is created?

Your getting a NullPointerException on the sqlQueries.java class line 101

Comment: yes, in  this line, values.put(dataBaseHelper.COMPANY_ID, companyid); dataBaseHelper is the instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your db ?

db.insert(dataBaseHelper.IMAGE_DATA, null, values);